# Javascript availheight is larger than browser window

Tags: javascript, window, height

When I set the height of an element to

```
screen.availHeight;
```

about 85px of content is cutoff at the bottom in Chrom and about 40px is cutoff from the bottom in IE and ff.  The cutoff content is under the windows taskbar.

how can I fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is'nt it obvious, you're getting the screen height, not the window height, so any browser chrome will not be subtracted (availHeight does actually subtract 40px from my screen height of 1200px, probably for the taskbar).

```
window.height;
```

Comment: +1. Yes, `screen.availHeight` gives the part of the desktop that is "available" for use after allowing for the taskbar (or non-Windows equivalanet). `screen.height` gives the full height. Both (can) get confused if you have more than one monitor connected. Neither tells you how big the browser window is, let alone the browser window's client area.

Comment: Yep, and the rest is probably browser chrome, as it seems to work with screen.availHeight for me (with 4 screens) if I put the browser in fullscreen, but not otherwise, then the same height as the browser chrome will dissapear at the bottom.

Comment: but I want the size of my elements to be relative to the size of the browser when its maximized.  If I use window.height and the browser is not maximized I get sizes relative to the smaller browser.

Comment: Yes you do, and as far as I know there is no easy way to do what you want.

Comment: So I think I still need to use screen.availheight.  Does anyone know why my content is being cutoff?  Is it the taskbar?

Comment: Nope, it's the browser chrome!

Comment: Its being cutoff in all browsers...chrome is a little worse

Comment: No, I did'nt mean the webbrowser Google Chrome specifically, I meant the browser "**chrome**", which is what the menus and borders of the browser is usually called, regardless of who made the browser.